# Find coordinates for rectangle with 2 corners that border a path, 1 known corner and 1 known side.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

[image: Track with rectangle, the coordinates of which I want]

Consider the image above. `DEGP` is a rectangle that I'm trying to draw programmatically so I need the coordinates of the points.

What's known is this:

- The coordinates of `D`
- The coordinates of the inside path that `P` and `G` are on (semi-circles with straight segments, nothing too weird).
- `DE` is 20 (as is `PG`, therefor)
- `D` is such that a rectangle like this will exist, `D` will never be lower than `C` or such that `PG` is either entirely on the straight or entirely on the semi-circle.

I can't seem to figure out how to get the coordinates of `E` or `G` or `P` because they're all dependent on each other. I tried to draw this by saying that a line from `D` straight down to `AB` should be equal to `EA`, but that gives a wonky result shown below:

[image: Attempt to define rectangle with wonky result]

Below is how I would do it if `PG` was entirely on the semi-circle:

[image: If PG was entirely on the semi-circle]

So I'd use the symmetry that the rectangle now has over line `AQ` to find `E` and draw `DP` and `EG` perpendicular until they meet the semi-circle.

***EDIT:*** I originally tagged this algebraic-geometry and I'm coming back to that with a possible approach to solve this:

The semi circle over `CJ` can be described as $x=-\sqrt{12.5^2-y^2}+\Delta AD$

What formula would describe the path of `G` as we rotate the rectangle around `D` and stretch `DP` (and thus `EG`) to have `P` be on the path. If I have that formula, I could equate it to the formula for the semi-circle to determine for which *y* point `G` is equal to a point on the semi-circle.

Is this a feasible approach?

Comment: This does not seem a trivial problem at all. Are there any restrictions on the choice of $D$, or do you know a priori that $D$ is chosen such that a rectangle of the type you have shown exists? How far have you gotten with any calculations? The way I would try and tackle this is to find the points $G$ and $P$ such that the line $GP$ is orthogonal to $DP$. Once you have found these points then $E$ is automatically defined. Have you tried something like this already?

Comment: You know a priori that such a rectangle exists. If `D` is such that `PG` would be entirely on the straight or entirely on the semi-circle, the problem is much easier and would be solved by a different calculation. Furthermore, the ovals actually represent a race-track, so if `D` is inside the inner oval or outside the outer oval, the calculation wouldn't be carried out. So far I've tried to split the rectangle into 2 triangles with line `DG` so I could maybe use trigonometry. But I'm unsure how to get the angle `EDG` from the DeltaY and DeltaX for `D` and `C` as those points are known.

Comment: (Edited the question with more info and example if `PG` is entirely on the semi-circle)

Comment: There is only one degree of freedom here, the position of $P$ on the inner path. This determines $G$ as the point on the path counterclockwise from $P$ with $|PG|=20$ (this is unique as long as the diameter $|CJ|\ge20$). Then the only thing left to solve for is the condition that $PD\perp PG$.

Comment: I don't see how the position of `P` is a degree of freedom as it is constraint by the fact that `PD` has to be equal to `EG` for it to be a rectangle. For every valid position of `D` (which is known) there really is only one possible rectangle. `CJ` is and will always be 25, coordinates and measurements of the inner path are fully known.

Comment: (Added algebraic approach I was thinking about to the bottom)